# Specific mongoose filter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to filter Booleans in a MongoDB with Mongoose in JavaScript.

A farm got the boolean takeCalfs. If takeCalfs is true it doesn't matter if isCalb ist true or false. But if takeCalfs is false, isCalb must be also false. The same for takeOxen and hasHorns. I'm currently struggling with integrating it into a mongoose query. The following works but only checks for same Booleans, how can I also check for a true => true or false query?

My goal is to filter if a farm is accepting calfs or cows with horns. But I don't know how to filter for multiple Booleans in mongo

```
const birthDate = new Date(entry.cow.age);
const ageInMilliseconds = Date.now() - birthDate;
const ageInYears = ageInMilliseconds / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

const isCalb = ageInYears <= 0.5;
const hasHorns = entry.cow.horning === "Ja";

const matchingFarms = await Farm.find({
      takeCalfs: isCalb,
      takeOxen: hasHorns,
    });
```

//EDIT

Few minutes after I post that, I got it

SOLUTION:

```js
const matchingFarms = await Farm.find({
        $or: [
          { takeCalfs: true },
          { $and: [{ takeCalfs: false }, { isCalb: false }] }
        ],
        $or: [
            { takeOxen: true },
            { $and: [{ takeOxen: false }, { hasHorns: false }] }
          ]
    });
```